# using external object in entity framework object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to use `Entity Framework` to store & retrieve some objects, one of the properties of which is a class which I have no control over.

For the sake of this problem description let's say I'm trying to persist `Arc` objects:

```
class Arc {
   public Angle start { get; set; }
   public Angle end { get; set; }
   // ... other properties ...
}
```

but I don't have write access to the `Angle` source, which has a public interface something like this:

```
class Angle {
   public enum Unit { Radians, Degrees };
   public Angle(double value, Unit units); // constructor
   public float Radians() { get; } // returns angle value in radians
   public float Degrees() { get; } // returns angle value in degrees
}
```

I presume I can do something in the DbContext's `OnModelCreating()` method to map the angle fields to a float column in the database but despite reading the `MSDN` docs, I've not been able to figure out what I need to do to accomplish this.

I somehow need to read the angle's Degrees (or Radians) property when storing the objects, then construct a new `Angle` using that value when retrieving them. How can I do this?

EDIT: I've thought of a poor solution, which is to make the Angle properties not mapped, and add an additional mapped property for each to do the conversion, something like this:

```
public float start_degrees { get { return start.Degrees; }
                              set { start = new Angle(value, Angle.Degrees); }
                             }
```

but I'd rather avoid this, because my object has many properties of this nature, so it would mean adding lots more.  I'm hoping there's a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I missunderstood the question, but let me give it try. How about this?

```
public class MyOwnTypeOfAngle
{

    public MyOwnTypeOfAngle(Angle input)
    {
        this.Radians = input.Radians;
        this.Degrees = input.Degrees;
    }


    public double Radians { get; set; }
    public double Degrees { get; set; }
}
```

In any case, when you want to change the configuration of your DbSets in EF, you set the following:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyNewConfigurationType ());
    }
```

***UPDATE***
ok, I haven't gotten so deep into configurations but I hope this may lead you in the right direction:

```
class MyNewConfigurationType : EntityTypeConfiguration<Arc>
 {
    public MyNewConfigurationType()
    {

        Ignore<Angle>(y => y.start);
        Ignore<Angle>(y => y.end);

        Property<float>(x => x.start.Degrees).HasColumnName("myStartDegrees");
        Property<float>(x => x.end.Degrees).HasColumnName("MyEndDegrees");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think it addresses my problem. If I understand you correctly, you're suggesting I wrap the existing Angle class in one I control, but unfortunately that's not really practical in this case (there are quite a a few such classes, and they're not as trivial as the Angle example I constructed).  I was hoping there was someway to insert a conversion method or something like that for "(de)serialization" when reading/writing to the database. (the double-float thing was just an error in my question; imagine everything's the same precision. I'll update my question).

Comment: Ah, OK. That seems to be half the solution - as I understand it, your solution would write the angle to the database as a number of degrees, which is perfect. But what about the inverse? When reading the data, my root object needs to end up with a correctly constructed Angle property, so at some point the Angle constructor needs calling with the correct parameters.